# re enable intellij java to kotlin conversion

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kotlin

I disabled the intellij dialog asking for converting Java code to Kotlin code on copy paste code from Java to Kotlin thinking that it would always convert without asking, but now it never converts. How can I enable this dialog again? I couldn't find any way to do it and now the IDE is not converting Java to Kotlin on copy + paste anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open preferences (Windows = `Ctrl-Alt-S`, Mac = `Cmd-,`).

Go to `Editor -> General -> Smart Keys` and scroll to the bottom.

The `Convert pasted Java code to Kotlin` and `Don't show Java to Kotlin conversion dialog during paste` options should be in the Kotlin section

Comment: After tick 1st option and untick 2nd option, I have no dialog sugession for convert while paste code. Why..? any idea..?

Comment: I needed "File ->Invalidate Caches / Restart" after do this.